# How to extract Performance Center Run ID during a load test?

Tags: loadrunner, vugen, hp-performance-center

I'm running a load test in Performance Center, and would like to extract the Run ID  to use within a VuGen test script.
I'm using version 12.55 of Performance Center and VuGen.
Vugen supports a number of informational functions, but these are vuser-centric(e.g. - whoami).
I'm looking for test run information during the test run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible with current version of API.

The documentation of all resources is https://admhelp.microfocus.com/pc/en/all/api_refs/Performance_Center_REST_API/Performance_Center_REST_API.htm

We can get the run stats only from when and where we actually started the test. For example, if we started the test using a REST call, we get the Run ID in response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Performance Center REST API to get the required information.
For more information on the REST API please check [REST API online documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/pc/en/12.55/api_refs/Performance_Center_REST_API/Performance_Center_REST_API.htm#Get-Extended-Run-Data.htm%3FTocPath%3DResources%7C_____13)

Comment: I had reviewed the REST APIs.
But it seemed like the RUN ID was required beforehand to get information.
Or I had to start the test via API to get a RUN ID. 
Is there a way to get the RUN ID of a currently running test that was started by Scheduler?